# Lock free ring buffer

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, lock-free

I am hoping that someone can take a look at my implementation of a lock-free ring buffer and critique the implementation.  I'm hoping that the focus can be of the correctness of the atomic operations and thread safety.

The buffer is implemented as a single producer/single consumer ring buffer, and owes a lot of boost's SPSC queue (unfortunately simply using `boost::spsc_queue` is not an option for my use case.  Therefore I rolled my own.

Usage details are as follows:

- Only 1 thread (producer) may call Push()
- Only 1 thread (consumer) may call Pop()
- *Either* the producer and consumer thread may call Read/WriteAvailable()

The main concern is that the atomic operations in ReadAvailable and WriteAvailable are correct for this use case.  Secondary concerns would be any performance gains that I can achieve to make operations on the buffer faster, as well as code style critique in general.

Many Thanks.

```
 * LockfreeBuffer.h
 *
 * Defines a lock free, single producer/single consumer queue
 * based around a ring buffer.  Only a single thread may call 
 * Push, and likewise a single thread may call Pop.  Push/Pop 
 * will fail with a false return value if the queue is full (push)
 * or empty (pop).  
 * ReadAvailable and WriteAvailable may be called from either the 
 * producer or consumer thread.
 */

#ifndef LOCKFREE_BUFFER_H
#define LOCKFREE_BUFFER_H

#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class LockfreeBuffer
{
 private:
    typedef std::size_t size_t;

    const size_t m_size;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_readIdx;
    // For Intel/AMD64, force m_readIdx and m_writeIdx onto
    // different cache lines with 64 bytes of padding
    // https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13186232
    unsigned char padding[64];
    std::atomic<size_t> m_writeIdx;

    std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_storage;

    static size_t ReadAvailable(
          size_t readIdx, size_t writeIdx, size_t size)
    {
       if(writeIdx >= readIdx)
          return writeIdx - readIdx;

       return writeIdx + size - readIdx;
    }

    static size_t WriteAvailable(
          size_t readIdx, size_t writeIdx, size_t size)
    {
       size_t ret = readIdx - writeIdx -1;
       if(writeIdx >= readIdx)
          ret += size;

       return ret;
    }

 public:
    LockfreeBuffer()                                   = delete;
    LockfreeBuffer(const LockfreeBuffer&)              = delete;
    LockfreeBuffer& operator=(const LockfreeBuffer&)   = delete;

    LockfreeBuffer(size_t size)
       : m_readIdx(0)
       , m_writeIdx(0)
       , m_size(size)
       , m_storage(std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[size]))
    { }

    bool Push(const T& obj)
    {
       const size_t nextWriteIdx = 
          (m_writeIdx.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1) % m_size;

       if(nextWriteIdx == m_readIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            return false; // Buffer is full

       m_storage[nextWriteIdx] = obj;

       m_writeIdx.store(nextWriteIdx, std::memory_order_release);

       return true;
    }

    bool Pop(T& obj)
    {  
       const size_t writeIdx = m_writeIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
       const size_t readIdx = m_readIdx.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
       
       if(ReadAvailable(readIdx, writeIdx, m_size) == 0)
          // Buffer is empty
          return false;

       obj = m_storage[readIdx];

       m_readIdx.store((readIdx + 1) % m_size, std::memory_order_release);

       return true;
    }

    size_t Size()
    {
       // Const, no need to acquire
       return m_size;
    }

    size_t ReadAvailable()
    {
       const size_t readIdx = m_readIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
       const size_t writeIdx = m_writeIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

       return ReadAvailable(readIdx, writeIdx, m_size);
    }

    size_t WriteAvailable()
    {
       const size_t readIdx = m_readIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
       const size_t writeIdx = m_writeIdx.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

       return WriteAvailable(readIdx, writeIdx, m_size);
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: If you have a test case that uses this code, it would help the question if you posted that test code in the question as well, otherwise this is a well asked question. The more code you post the better review you will get.